# Getting info from html table via htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, windows-8.1, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with getting information from html table via htmlagilitypack.

html (www.ldoceonline.com/search/?q=arg) looks like this

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><td><a href><span/></a><span/><span/><span><a/><a/></span></td> //I want to get information from here, from a href and spans.
                    <td>...
                    </tr>
                    </table>
...
```

My c# code.

```
var url = String.Format(urlToTheSite);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().LoadFromWebAsync(url).Result;

HtmlNodeCollection tablesHtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.. //stack in here
```

And I have a problem because in articles which I found I only see answers like this:

```
var url = String.Format(urlToTheSite);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load();
HtmlNodeCollection tablesHtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(nodeToSelect);
```

But I don't have method Load for HtmlWeb I only have this ones: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VvEO.jpg
also I didn't have method SelectNodes for DocumentNode in HtmlNodeCollection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5wiG.jpg

I trying something like this, but I get only 4 results #comment/#text/html/text and I don't know how to go deeper.

```
HtmlDocument doc = await new HtmlWeb().LoadFromWebAsync(urlToTheSite);
var tablesHtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.ToList().Where(x => x.OriginalName.Equals("html")).ToList();//this one result one result
```

Thanks for help, also if it depends I wrote an universal app for Window8.1/WP8.1.

Answer (score 0):

> "...if it depends I wrote an universal app for Window8.1/WP8.1."

Yes, it depends on the platform. HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) for universal apps doesn't have `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()`, because both requires xpath which isn't supported in this platform. You can rely only on LINQ API of HAP in this case, for example to get all tables in the page you can do as follow (return 4 results):

```
var tables = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").ToList();
```